# How to send a SNMP GET request with wrong type using net-snmp?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, winsnmp

How could I send a net-snmp GET request, such that:

netsnmp_check_vb_type

will return SNMP_ERR_WRONGTYPE?

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to modify the agent you were talking to so that it would send back that error code for a GET.  No agent out there should be doing that for a GET request unless there was a bug in the agent.  In other words: you'd have to put a bug in the agent!

Answer (score 0):

I think that's impossible, as wrong type check should only work for SET requests.